# In the context of QM, is it correct to say that the Dirac delta is like a continuous version of the Kronecker delta?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Thinking about observables, there is continuous observables such as position and discrete observables such as energy of an electron in an atom.

**For the discrete case, we have:**

Suppose we have a orthonormal basis {$|E_i \rangle $}, which means that each vector has length 1, $\langle E_i|E_i \rangle = 1$; and are mutually orthogonal, $\langle E_i|E_j \rangle = 0$, $i \neq j$. We can condense these two conditions in one using the Kronecker delta:
$$\langle E_i|E_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$$

So if we have an orthonormal basis we can expand an arbitrary quantum state in this basis and in order to get a particular coeffincient ($E_2$, for example) we use the inner product with the second basis vector and then we write the inner product as a Kronecker delta.

$$\langle E_2 | \psi \rangle = \sum_i c_i \langle E_2 | E_i \rangle \rightarrow \langle E_2 | \psi \rangle = \sum_i c_i \delta_{2i}.$$

And finally when the indices match, we get the coefficient we want, $\langle E_2 | \psi \rangle = c_2 \delta_{22} = c_2$

**For the continuous case, we have (shortly):**

If we want $c(3)$, as an example, we use the inner product and the use the Dirac delta:

$$|\psi \rangle = \int dx  c(x) |x \rangle$$
$$c(3) = \int dx c(x) \delta(3 - x).$$

***So, is the Dirac delta the same that Kronecker delta, but continuous?***

Edit: my question is if it's correct or if exist some particular property of the usage of each tool that I'm missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here as an answer except "Yes.", which is too short to even submit as an answer.

Comment: Sorry. I edited it to be more clear. My question is if it's correct or if exist some particular property of the usage of each tool that I'm missing, because they both have aplications besides QM

Comment: Essentially a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538614/25301 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479892/25301, maybe others?

Comment: One of thier usage is that both the Dirac delta function and the Kronecker delta function are used to represent orthogonality

Comment: The two deltas are both "identity matrices". One important dissimilarity is the Dirac isn't dimensionless until you include the integration operator.

Comment: Yes, the Dirac delta "function" is a *continuum* version of the Kronecker delta ("continuous" isn't applicable to the Dirac delta). I am sure that is the exact reason Paul Dirac chose $\delta$ as the symbol to use for it (though I have no historical evidence). It is possible mathematically to express the finite dimensional and infinite dimensional cases the exact same way. Dirac actually attempted to do so in his "The Principles of Quantum Mechanics", but was not familiar enough to be fully successful.